# How to write to multiple GPIOs at the same time

Tags: gpio

I just wrote the following code for the sake of this question:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

christmas_led = (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

patterns = {1:(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), 2:(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)}

for led in christmas_led:
    GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(led, 0)

try:
    while True:
        for i in 1,2:
            for j in range(8):
                GPIO.output(christmas_led[j], patterns[i][j])
            time.sleep(0.5)

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have used `for j in range(8)` loop to write to outputs one by one. To my knowledge this procedure takes place in a sequential manner. Is there a way to do to write to all outputs at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to raspberry-gpio-python documentation ([here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Outputs/)) you can output to several channels at the same time by passing 2 list parameters instead of 2 integers.

Example:

> To output to several channels at the same time:
>
> ```
> chan_list = (11,12)
> GPIO.output(chan_list, GPIO.LOW) # all LOW
> GPIO.output(chan_list, (GPIO.HIGH,GPIO.LOW))  # first HIGH, second LOW
> ```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the same time.  The implementation of the examples you give sequences through the list of GPIO and outputs to each GPIO in turn.  The GPIO are not written at the same instance in time (i.e. the output for all GPIO is not simultaneous).

Answer (score 4):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library Python [module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) lets you clear multiple GPIO or set multiple GPIO at the same instant.

[clear_bank_1](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#clear_bank_1) will set multiple GPIO low.

[set_bank_1](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_bank_1) will set multiple GPIO high.

**Example**

To set GPIO 5, 10, 23 low.

```
pi.clear_bank_1( (1<<5) | (1<<10) | (1<<23) )
```

To set GPIO 3, 6, 7 high.

```
pi.set_bank_1( (1<<3) | (1<<6) | (1<<7) )
```